# How to add the values to the List<long[]> from the text file?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a text file this is a small part of him its format:

```
DANNY VIDEO HISTOGRAM DATA
FORMAT VERSION:1.00
SOURCE: <MVI_2483.AVI_Automatic>
DATA: 
Frame 000000: 5977,40775,174395,305855,265805
Frame 000001: 5432,21333,456789,123456,111111
```

Now every line Frame.....Have 256 numbers 5977,40775,174395,305855,265805
In the example i show here only 5 numbers but each line/frame have 256 numbers.

In Form1 i have a List: List Histograms

What i need to do is to read the text file in this case the text file name is Histograms.txt to read the text file and each line/frame with 256 numbers i need to add back to the List.
So the List Histograms will be in the end that in index [0] for example i will have 256 indexes in [0] 5977 in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcrUp.jpg) 40775 in [2] 174395 in [3] 305955 in [4] 265805 and so on 256 numbers.

Then in index [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcrUp.jpg) again 256 numbers ...
Then in index [2] and so on...

In the end i should have in the List 3803 index that each index have inside 256 index that each one contain a number.

This is the code of how i am writing the text file when the List is with the numbers and then when i am running the program again i need that it will read and load the text file back to the List. When i am running the program the List is empty.

```
private void WriteHistograms() // For automatic mode only for now
{
    HistogramsFile = new StreamWriter(_outputDir + "\\" + averagesListTextFileDirectory + "\\"  + "Histograms.txt", false, Encoding.ASCII);
    HistogramsFile.WriteLine("DANNY VIDEO HISTOGRAM DATA\r\nFORMAT VERSION:1.00\r\nSOURCE: " + "<" + averagesListTextFile + ">" + "\r\nDATA: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < Histograms.Count; i++)
    {
        HistogramsFile.Write("Frame " + i.ToString("D6") + ": ");
        for (int x = 0; x < Histograms[i].Length; x++ )
        {
            HistogramsFile.Write(Histograms[i][x] + ",");
        }
        HistogramsFile.WriteLine("!");
    }
    HistogramsFile.WriteLine("DATA");
    HistogramsFile.Close();
}
```

Now i have another function: LoadHistograms(), i need to read the text file and add back the numbers to the List.

I added now a photo of the List how it is when writing it to the text file and how the List should looks like after reading it back from the text file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have a fairly good idea how to get it done by using this piece of code.

```
string line;
List<long[]> list = new List<long[]>();

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"..\..\Histograms.txt"))
{
    do { line = file.ReadLine(); } while (!line.Trim().Equals("DATA:"));                               

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        long[] valArray = new long[256];

        var split = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
        if (split.Length == 2)
        {
            var valArrayStr = split[1].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            for (int i = 0; i < valArrayStr.Length; i++)
            {
                int result;
                if (int.TryParse(valArrayStr[i].Trim(), out result))
                    valArray[i] = result;
            }
        }
        list.Add(valArray);
    }
}
```

Happy Coding...